# Reading appended file data

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

So I set up a dictionary from a .csv file via

```
meta = {}
with open('metadata.csv') as metad:
    for m in csv.DictReader(metad):
        meta[m["term"]] = m
    metad.close()
```

Then I let the user update the dictionary via:

```
metan = open("metadata.csv", "ab")
metaw = csv.writer(metan)
root = raw_input("What is a \n").lower()
pos = raw_input("What is b \n").lower()
if pos in ("y", "n"):
    c = raw_input("What is c? \n").lower()
else:
    c = ""
data = ["other",a,b,c]
metaw.writerow(data)
metan.close()
```

Immediately afterwards I try to show what was written (and this is where the problem lies) with

```
print meta
```

When it prints, it will show all of the data that's already there, but not the recently appended data. How can I display that?
Thanks

Comment: Are you expecting edits to the `.csv` file to automatically update your dictionary? That's not how that works at all - you have to either manually update the dictionary or reparse the whole file. The first is obviously better.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper That is what I was expecting. I'm now thoroughly disappointed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you expect `meta` to show the new data, you never added anything to it! :-)

You should probably update `meta` at the same time you call `metaw.writerow()`.